# How to insert Data into a Database c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How To Take The Data From The Input boxes and insert it into the Database using the dataset?

This is what I have right Now in the Data Service Class:

```
public void Update(DataTable dt)
    {

        try
        {
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + dt.TableName + "]", cn);
            cn.Open();
            OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
            cb.QuotePrefix = "[";
            cb.QuoteSuffix = "]";



            da.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }

    }
```

And this is the Button Click

```
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                    //dc = DataService Class
                    //ds = DataSet From DataService Class
                dc.Update(ds.Tables["Customers"]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Is is Possible to Insert on da.Update?
This works Fine when you Edit in the DataGridView and Then Click the btninsert it gets inserted. How would I take input from Textboxes and insert it into the Database?

Comment: input box means textboxes in grid?

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. No Just Taking what the User has in putted and inserting it into the Database

Answer (score 0):

Question is bit unclear , but, if you want to take input from textboxes in gridview then you can simply write following code:

```
val1=dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column name"].Value.ToString();
```

Or

```
val1=dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[Column index].Value.ToString();
```

(Note: i will always recomend you first line of code)

Then simply create command object and fire insert command to insert each value in database.